# Not able to retrieve object property from Chunk Template Engine

Tags: java, android, html, string, chunk-templates

I have created a list of objects and I am trying to retrieve object name from template. The template engine is Chunk Template Engine.
The object list is created like this:

```
 html.set("items", new Item[]{new Item("Item 1", 2),new Item("Item 2", 5)} );
```

The Item class looks like this:

```
public class Item {

private String mName;
private float mPrice;

public Item(String name, float price) {
    this.mName = name;
    this.mPrice = price;
}

public String getName() {
    return mName;
}

public float getPrice() {
    return mPrice;
}
```

and the way I am trying to access the item is:

```
{.loop in $items as $item}
    <div>
        <span>{$item.get_name}</span>
    </div>
{/loop}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try just `{$item.name}`

The "get" is removed from the property name in the template -- from the [docs](http://www.x5software.com/chunk/examples/ChunkExample?example=pojo):

```
-- Standard accessors like getFullName() are exposed in the template
-- as {$tag.full_name} - camelCase converts to lower_with_underscores
```